# javascript plugin wont return the length of elements

Tags: javascript

I found a tutorial about writing a custom JavaScript plugin but I cann't get it working as I want to.
I'm trying to see if the elements are present(length) but this returns an undefined value. When I use vanilla JavaScript it returns a value.

```
var $ = (function () {

    'use strict';

    var Constructor = function (selector) {
        if (!selector) return;
        if (selector === 'document') {
            this.nodes = [document];
        } else if (selector === 'window') {
            this.nodes = [window];
        } else {
            this.nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        }
    };

    Constructor.prototype.ready = function(callback) {
        if(callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                if(document.readyState === "interactive" || document.readyState === "complete") {
                    return callback();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    Constructor.prototype.each = function (callback) {
        if (!callback || typeof callback !== 'function') return;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
            callback(this.nodes[i], i);
        }
        return this;
    };

    Constructor.prototype.addClass = function (className) {
        this.each(function (item) {
            item.classList.add(className);
        });
        return this;
    };

    var init = function (selector) {
        return new Constructor(selector);
    };

    return init;

})();

$('body').length;//not working
document.querySelectorAll('body').length;//working
$('body').addClass('active');//working
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `$('body').nodes.length`?

Comment: There is no `Constructor.prototype.length`, and `Constructor` does not inherit any base class. So why do you expect `$('body').length` to work here?

Comment: Don't use `$` as your plugin name -- anyone using it will think it's jQuery.

Comment: @Barmar that kinda seems like the point. But in all honesty the whole explicit revealing module pattern in general is just a really outdated practice for JavaScript.

Comment: also the $(this) is outputting an error with document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define your own `length` property:

```
    var Constructor = function (selector) {
        if (!selector) return;
        if (selector === 'document') {
            this.nodes = [document];
        } else if (selector === 'window') {
            this.nodes = [window];
        } else {
            this.nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        }
        this.length = this.nodes.length;
    };
```

If you add any methods that modify the contents of `this.nodes`, they'll also need to update `this.length`. Or, as Bronzdragon suggests, you can define a getter to get it dynamically.

Comment: Right, I changed it to a property.

Comment: also the $(this) is outputting an error with document.querySelectorAll

Comment: The argument to `Constructor()` has to be a CSS selector string. `this` is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You save the nodes internally as `this.nodes`. This means that `this` does not have a concept of length. If you want to add this property explicitly, you can create [a getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for it. Otherwise, you can get the length by accessing the `nodes` property:

```
$('body').nodes.length;
```

Comment: nice did not know about a getter