# How to get and pass the clicked element as THIS inside a addEventListener

Tags: javascript

So I'm building a small custom JS library like jQuery but I ran into an wall.

I have build a event delegation function which I will be using for a simple click event.

Within this prototype part I will run some logic(in this example a addClass) but it does not work with the this keyword. As I need to add for example a class to the the clicked element.

```
Constructor.prototype.on = function (eventName , elementSelector, callback) {
    document.addEventListener(eventName, function(e) {
        for (var target = e.target; target && target != this; target = target.parentNode) {
            if (target.matches(elementSelector)) {
                callback.call(target, e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }, false);
};

// X is the plugin
X('body').on('click','.someClass',function(){
     X(this).addClass('clicked');// not going to work 
});
```

Comment: From your last question, the argument to `X()` needs to be a selector, not a DOM element.

Comment: Have you redesigned your plugin to allow `X(element)` as well?

Comment: not sure what you mean, im still a js noob ;-)

Comment: In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255693/javascript-plugin-wont-return-the-length-of-elements) the `Constructor` class does `document.querySelectorAll(selector)`. `this` is not a selector, it's a DOM element, you can't do `document.querySelectorAll(this)`.

Comment: If you want to allow that, you should add another check to your constructor. If `selector` isn't a string, just set `this.nodes = [selector];`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I would say post the answer so that I can vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `Constructor` function so that it allows you to provide a DOM element, not just a selector, as a parameter. Then you can use `X(this)` to create an instance of your class that contains `this` element.

```js
var Constructor = function(selector) {
  if (!selector) return;
  if (typeof selector != string) {
    this.nodes = [selector];
  } else if (selector === 'document') {
    this.nodes = [document];
  } else if (selector === 'window') {
    this.nodes = [window];
  } else {
    this.nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  }
  this.length = this.nodes.length;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. If you have any more tips on this part let me know :-)